# How to post text variable in angular to mysql trough php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

so I have a little bit tricky or rather say odd situation.

I have php and mysql database, for frontend I am using angular.js

So I am creating service, that sends data, via post request to php.

So everything is working properly when I am sending input values via name html attribute.

But problem appears when I am trying to send hardcoded text variable from for loop.

I know it's very hardcoded way for doing it but i don't know how to do it differently.

So here is my php

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','nemkeang','nemkic23','interventure');

if(!$conn) {
 die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


$text = $_POST['first_name'];
$text2 = $_POST['last_name'];
$text3 = $_POST['date'];
$text4 = $_POST['author'];
$text5 = $_POST['note'];
$text6 = $_POST['skill'];
$target = "/assets";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['cv_file_name']['name']);
//This gets all the other information from the form
$file_name=  $_FILES['cv_file_name']['name'];
$file_name2=  $_FILES['cv_file_name']['name'];


//Writes the file to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cv_file_name']['tmp_name'], "./".$file_name)) {
    //Tells you if its all ok
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['cv_file_name']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
    // Connects to your Database
    }


$sql = "INSERT INTO user (first_name, last_name, skill, date, cv_file_name, cv_url, author, note)
VALUES ('$text','$text2','$text6','$text3','$file_name','$file_name2','$text4','$text5')";

if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
else {
    echo "success";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The php is working correctly it's sending data, but on the     $text6 = $_POST['skill']; problem arrives.

So here is my angular service first

```
app.service('testpost',['$http',function($http){
    this.saveRecipe = function(postdata){

        let payload = new FormData();
        payload.append("first_name", postdata.first_name);
        payload.append('last_name', postdata.last_name);
        payload.append('date', postdata.date);
        payload.append('cv_file_name', postdata.cv_file_name);
        payload.append('author', postdata.author); 
        payload.append('note', postdata.note); 
        payload.append('skill', postdata.skill); 

        return $http.post('login/post.php', payload, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},

        })
    }
}]);
```

And it's also working correctly, when i log it to console, it shows correct values. Just don't send  payload.append('skill', postdata.skill); value to php.

Here is my controller

```
app.controller('newUser',['$scope','$filter','testpost', function($scope,$filter,testpost) {
        $scope.postdata = {}
        $scope.arr = [];
        let bar = document.getElementsByClassName('md-chip-content');

        this.saveRecipe = function(postdata) {
        for(var i = 0;  i < bar.length;  i++) {
            $scope.arr.push(bar[i].innerText);   
        }   
            let skills = $scope.arr;
            postdata.date = $filter('date')(postdata.date, "MM/dd/yyyy").split('/').join('-');
            postdata.skill  = skills[0];
            postdata.skill2 = skills[1];
            postdata.skill3 = skills[2];
            postdata.skill4 = skills[3];
            testpost.saveRecipe(postdata).then((data)=>{
                console.log(data); 
            })
            error:(err) =>{ return false};
        }

    }]);
```

Just to be clear i just want the value from postadata.skill to be sent to mysql via php. And I think the problem is in php because the value don't come from input type.

I hope that I've explained everything well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: why you using php post request ?You should use angular way to post data by using ng-model.

Comment: I am not too sure whether this would work or not.. Create a hidden input field in your form named skill. Might work. Because then there actually would be a form element named skill which can be accessed thru $_POST.

Comment: check if postdata.skill or skills[0] is not undefined using console